# error 401 POST en axios react

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

el problema es que tengo un error 401 (Unauthorized) con axios, crei que era por permisos de spotify o algo asi, pero cuando probe el token en Postman si me da el resultado esperado (Cambiar de cancion)
Encontre algunas preguntas parecidas pero no tenian respuesta jaja
Tambien intente hacer la funcion asincrona, y la peticion GET si me funciona
Este es el codigo que hace la peticion, se activa desde un boton

```
    Next() {
    const token=localStorage.getItem("TK")
    console.log(token)
    axios.post('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/next',
    {
        headers:
        {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            Authorization:'Bearer'+token
        }

    })

}
```

Comment: No te estaras equivocando de verbo HTTP?, si estas enviando contenido por POST por que no tiene adjuntado un body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se te ha pasado poner el espacio después de Bearer

```
{
   Authorization:'Bearer '+token
}
```